# Windows 10 SSHFS Suddenly Stopped Working - System Error 67

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, sshfs

I've been successfully using SSHFS on my Windows 10 computer to mount a VirtualBox Ubuntu drive for over a year. Then, suddenly today, I started getting System error 67. I've used the same exact command every time and up until today, had never had any issues.

Please see below:

```
PS C:\Users\John> net use N: \\sshfs\john@127.0.0.1!5679\..\..
The password is invalid for \\sshfs\john@127.0.0.1!5679\..\...

Enter the user name for 'sshfs': john
Enter the password for sshfs:
System error 67 has occurred.

The network name cannot be found.
```

I don't believe I have changed anything. The only difference is that today, I am in a different location than usual; however, I frequently move around and this has not been an issue prior. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Update: It turned out that WinFsp somehow got corrupted and I just had to run the installer and have it repair. That fixed the issue.

Comment: Happy you figured this out! But since it is a non-issue for other and idiosyncratic to your setup, it might be best to not post this update as an answer and just delete the whole question itself.